# Android: How can I packed some shapes into one resource file?

Tags: android, resources, shapes

I've made a few shapes in drawable folder, is it possible to packed them in one resource file? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can take indivitual images and place them one after the other with the

android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="6px" parameters..

but it is not possible by default in android

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible, by using level-list XML element.
If you look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702143/multipe-shapes-inside-shapes-xml-in-android) it shows you how to do it.
You can even define the drawable within the level-list