# Inline definition of non-Bitmap drawables in LayerList or LevelList XML items

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-drawable, layer-list

The documentation of the XML resource specification of [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) and [LevelList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList) drawables says that the `item` element will only accept `bitmap` as child element. On some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702143/multipe-shapes-inside-shapes-xml-in-android) concerning level lists, I see that people are adding `shape` tags as children to the `item` tags. I tried out the following and it seems to work nicely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:maxLevel="0">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:maxLevel="1">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</level-list>
```

Here is my question. **Is this documented anywhere, or should I avoid this kind of construct because it is not supported in all API versions, or is the documentation simply incomplete and the above is perfectly legal?**

To clarify, I know that I can specify any sort of drawable by using separate resource files and referring to them using the `android:drawable` attribute. **The question refers to the inline specification of arbitrary drawables within the XML of the layer list or level list.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES, it is allowed and supported behaviour.

While it is not documented, non-bitmap tags are used in the official Android XML resources. For example the source of [progress_large_holo.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/progress_large_holo.xml) contains the following.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_outer_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="0"
             android:toDegrees="1080" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="720"
             android:toDegrees="0" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Other sources also reveal that any XML that is accepted as a drawable resource can be placed inside the `item` tags.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't state that it only accepts `Bitmap` objects, but that it will accept them.  You can use the `android:drawable` to specify a drawable.  Pull your shapes into their own drawable XML definition and reference them in the level-list.

Comment: I know that I can specify any kind of drawable using the `android:drawable` attribute. My question refers to the XML specification. Can I specify shapes (or other drawables for that matter) inline inside the item tag. his means that I don't create multiple resources for every level or layer.

Comment: You're right in that the documentation isn't exactly clear, other than it states that any child of <code><selector></code> will work.

Comment: No, that's not quite correct. In the documentation of `<level-list>` it is stated that `<item>` "must be a child of a `<selector>` element." This is clearly wrong because `<selector>` defines a `StateListDrawable` and `<level-list>` defines a `LevelListDrawable`. 

The documentation also states that `<item>` "accepts child `<bitmap>` elements". While this is true, it is incomplete. Apparently it can accept child `<shape>` elements as well. I just wanted to know if it is safe for me to do so or if there might be some incompatibilities on some API versions.